# Facebook send dialog is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need help in  facebook send dialog function,
 send dialog not showing. I get no error, but no send dialog box is showing.
What is the problem in below code?

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        sendDialog();
    }
}

var sendDialog = function()  {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        display: 'iframe',
        name: 'sample',
        link: 'https://www.sample.com/'
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the grammar-fixed and indentation-fixed version to add details. We don't want to fix that again, and I can't spot your edit in the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the following in your body tag ?

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // assume we are already logged in
  FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxx', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
 FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
      link: 'url',
      });
</script>
```

Note: use `method: 'send',`

For details refer:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: yaa, i have .used this function.problem is not showing dialog interface.

Comment: can you place some alert inside the "var sendDialog = function()  {" ?is it triggered while calling the function?

Comment: i used my body tag inside this fuction ,window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxx', xfbml: true, cookie: true}); }); i want to response.authResponse show  send dialog.

Comment: @Soojoo, could you help please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654709/facebook-sdk-send-method-in-reactjs